# How can I resize my window in bluestacks?

Tags: bluestacks

I just downloaded bluestacks, but it's unusable because it refuses to size itself to something that will fit on my screen, and I can't resize it.

I've tried the regedit method (all references to seem to be out of date, since I have GuestHeight/Width and WindowHeight/Width instead of just "Height" and "Width"). I can get the loading screen to come up with my specified dimensions, but after initialization it reverts the size back to something else. I did make sure to kill all the bluestacks processes via the task manager. I'm in windows 7, and I should mention i have 3 screens, one of which is a different resolution.

So how can I reliably change the size of the current version of bluestacks?